# Regex - Select pattern within string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm new to Regex and facing a complicated !

I want to select ONLY the amount + the currency from the following list item.

Exemple: 150,00 Euro - 100,00 Libra ESTERLINA etc.

```
Monto: 150,00 EURO
Monto: 7.350,00 PESO URUGUAY | Pesos: 12.495,00 |Sucursal: 36| 
Monto: 2.500,00 PESO URUGUAY 
Monto: 200,00 U$S EEUU | Pesos: 12.550,00 
Monto: 50,00 U$S EEUU 
Monto: 700,00 REAL | Pesos: 10.500,00 | Sucursal: 101 
Monto: 100,00 LIBRA ESTERLINA | Pesos: 8.500,00 | Sucursal: 12
Monto: 5.000,00 PESO CHILENO | Pesos: 400,00 | Sucursal: 101
```

My regex test: https://regex101.com/r/R5Edrk/2

```
[0-9,.].+(Euro|URUGUAY|EEUU|CHILENO|ESTERLINA|REAL)
```

I tried various combinations and formula but dont succeed to isolate amount + currency. 
I also tried to select all the string untile the boundary "|" (the first vertical bar) but it didnt work...

Any help and explication is welcomed, thanks community ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the demo, but you need to also point on here in your question exactly what you are trying to match.  What is your acceptance criteria?

Comment: You could group the alternatives combining `\b[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)*[ \t]+(?:Euro|PESO URUGUAY|U\$S EEUU|REAL|LIBRA ESTERLINA|PESO CHILENO)` https://regex101.com/r/5gNGkR/1 Where the match for the digits is not specific.

Comment: Thank you! Just in my case it unfortunately doesnt work because Im working with Regex RE2 (from Google marketing products) and it doesnt accept the exactly match \$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Rather new to RegEx but what about something along [these](https://regex101.com/r/R5Edrk/5) lines?

```
(?<=Monto:\s).*?(?=\s\||$)
```

- `(?<=Monto:\s)` - Negative LookBehind to set startposition after `Monto:`
- `.*?` - any character as many times possible but lazy (stop when there is a match)
- `(?=\s\||$)` - Positive LookAhead for any `\s` (space) followed by either a literal pipe symbol or end string.

Comment: Thank you, very beautiful solution :D

Comment: Just in my case it unfortunately doesnt work because Im working with Regex RE2 (from Google marketing products) and it doesnt accept the exactly match  \|

Comment: @ELT, I'm confused as RE2 documentation suggest to escape the pipe symbol exactly like this. I guess I'm not familiar enough to tell you why it wouldn't work. Sorry.

Comment: @ELT, have you had any luck? I have tried some things on Google Spreadsheets `RegexExtract` hoping it mimics the behaviour you are experiencing. Does `"\d*.?\d*,?\d+[^\|]*"` work for you? If it has been solved. Please don't forget to accept an answer to close your thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the pattern more specific by combining the amount and the currency in the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
\b[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)*[ \t]+(?:Euro|PESO URUGUAY|U\$S EEUU|REAL|LIBRA ESTERLINA|PESO CHILENO)
```

- `\b` Word boundary to prevent the word being part of a longer word
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:[.,][0-9]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching either a dot or comma and 1+ digits
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ spaces or tabs
- `(?:` Non capture group to match one of the alternatives

  - `Euro|PESO URUGUAY|U\$S EEUU|REAL|LIBRA ESTERLINA|PESO CHILENO`
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5gNGkR/1)

The documentation about [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) states `To match a metacharacter, escape it with a backslash`

You could look into the documentation to see if you are using the right function that accepts a regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Regex RE2 is really restrictive and Google marketing products like Google Data Studio really strict with that... I finally cant do what I was ltrying to do but it doest matter. Fun to discover new Regex tricks, first of all :)

Comment: WHY `\b[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)*[ \t]+(?:Euro|PESO URUGUAY|U\$S EEUU|REAL|LIBRA ESTERLINA|PESO CHILENO)` AND NOT `:?[0-9.,].+[ \t]+(?:Euro|PESO URUGUAY|U\$S EEUU|REAL|LIBRA ESTERLINA|PESO CHILENO)` ?

Comment: I think I get your question  This part `[0-9.,].+` matches 1+ occurrences of any of the listed. That means is will also match just `...,,,...` without any digit. If you use `[0-9.,].+` it will match only a single occurrence of the listed and any char (due to the `.`) 1 or more times which will first match all characters.